# Integral of exponential times $\frac{x^2}{x^2+a}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Is it possible to find the indefinite integral of:

$$
y = \frac{x^2}{x^2 + a} e^{-(x+b)^2}
$$

I have tried integration by parts but haven't been successful. Maybe its possible considering a special function?

Answer (score 3):

As $\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+a} = 1 - \dfrac{a}{x^2+a},$ then we can rewrite the integral in question as
$$ \int \dfrac{x^2}{x^2+a} e^{-(x+b)^2}dx=\int e^{-(x+b)^2}dx - a\int \dfrac{e^{-(x+b)^2}}{x^2+a}dx.$$

Since $\int e^{-(x+b)^2}dx = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi} \operatorname{erf}(x+b),$ then it's clear you'll need special functions. I don't believe there's a well known formulation in terms of special functions.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Shouldn't there be an a in front of the second term?

Comment: Yes, thank you! I appreciate you letting me know. Please let me know if you happen to find anything else that is incorrect.